# Can namespace functions be declared at block scope?

Tags: c++, scope, namespaces, function-declaration

Can namespace functions be declared at block scope outside the namespace they were defined at?

This code does  not compile when `DECLARED_IN_NS` is defined as `1`:

```
#define DECLARED_IN_NS 1 // can be either 0 or 1


#if DECLARED_IN_NS == 1
namespace ns
{
#endif

void
func1()
{
}

void
func2()
{
}

#if DECLARED_IN_NS == 1
} // namepace ns
#endif

int main( )
{
#if DECLARED_IN_NS == 1

    void ns::func1(); // compile error
    void ns::func2(); // compile error

    ns::func1();
    ns::func2();

#elif DECLARED_IN_NS == 0

    void func1();
    void func2();

    func1();
    func2();

#endif
}
```

It shows some errors:

```
error: qualified-id in declaration before '(' token
   28 |     void ns::func1();
      |                   ^
```

The code compiles when `func1` and `func2` are defined at global namespace. However, it doesn't compile when they are defined inside a namespace (e.g. `ns`).

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: when the declarations are outside of `main` its the same issue, but the errors are much clearer https://godbolt.org/z/3o9e6nxqr

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Hmm I see. So it appears that there's no way to get around this. Fine.

Comment: @Adrian Mole Interesting. I use the latest stable version of GCC. Haven't tried it on other compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find a definitive reference to this in the standard, but I don't think there'd be much point to allow it intentionally.

Even if it *could* appear at block scope, it'd be pointless. A declaration that uses a nested name specifier cannot be the first declaration for an entity.

> **[dcl.meaning.general]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.meaning.general#1.sentence-3) When the declarator-id is qualified, the declaration shall refer to a previously declared member of the class or namespace to which the qualifier refers (or, in the case of a namespace, of an element of the inline namespace set of that namespace ([namespace.def])) ...

This makes this code like this valid

```
namespace ns
{
void func();

} // namepace ns


void ns::func(); // repeated declaration - optional
void ns::func() { // definition
}
```

Now, returning to the block scope case, you'd need a namespace scoped declaration preceding it anyway, so the whole exercise is moot.

Furthermore, the behavior of declaring functions in block scope has [aspects that are aptly named by the c++ community](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), but it remains due to C compatibility. It would certainly not be beneficial to allow it for nested names intentionally.

Comment: It can help make the code a bit less error prone and clearer in a few specific scenarios. But yeah, it's not that useful overall. I'll revert back to declaring in namespace scope.

Comment: @digito_evo- I assume you mean working around shadowing? A using declaration achieves that too. And it doesn't require one to repeat prototypes.

Comment: I mean it can be useful for functions that are only called in a single function `foo()`, we can declare them locally in the `foo()` and so make sure that no one else in the file scope except `foo()` will have access to the declarations of those functions. It's like hiding some functions that are not supposed to be used by any other part of the code.